# How to get certificate from Azure KeyVault as .crt and .key files?

Tags: powershell, certificate, azure-keyvault

I need to export a certificate from Azure KeyVault to VM as .crt file with its key as .key file.
I found on ms docs following article: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.keyvault/get-azkeyvaultcertificate?view=azps-4.6.1#example-2--get-cert-and-save-it-as-pfx) and then with openssl convert it to correct files.

Unfortunately, there's one restriction for me that I cannot use openssl.
So my question, is there any way to do it with powershell?

Comment: Do you mind if we use c# to implement it?

Comment: @JimXu I don't mind as long as it is possible to be triggered from powershell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When a Key Vault certificate is created, an addressable key and secret
> are also created with the same name. The Key Vault key allows key
> operations and the Key Vault secret allows retrieval of the
> certificate value as a secret. A Key Vault certificate also contains
> public x509 certificate metadata.
> Source: [Composition of a Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/about-keys-secrets-certificates?redirectedfrom=MSDN#composition-of-a-certificate).

You can use new [az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az) ([CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest) based) in powershell to [download the crt (public part)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-download), [export the private key from secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/secret?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-secret-download) or [export the public key from key (in case you need only the public key)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/key?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-key-download) separately like below.

> Note: The policy used to create the certificate must indicate that the
> key is exportable. If the policy indicates non-exportable, then the
> private key isn't a part of the value when retrieved as a secret.
> Source: [Exportable or Non-exportable key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/about-keys-secrets-certificates?redirectedfrom=MSDN#exportable-or-non-exportable-key).

```
# download as crt in DER format
# you can also download in PEM format by changing to -e PEM
az keyvault certificate download --vault-name <keyvault-name> -n <cert-name> -f cert.crt -e DER

# private key is stored in secret, exporting separately
az keyvault secret download --vault-name <keyvault-name> -n <cert-name> -f cert.key

# key is stored in key, exporting public part separately in PEM format
# you can also download in DER format by changing to -e DER
# you cannot retrieve private part from key
az keyvault key download --vault-name <keyvault-name> -n <cert-name> -f public-key.pem -e PEM
```

Note: If the format is PKCS#12 when you uploaded the certificate, then the second command (private key) would download in p12 format which would require the passphrase.

[image]

Comment: This is a really great answer! Thank you